# jquery check empty field of previous element

Tags: jquery, performance

I have 5 input text (answer option) that will give error if there is blank input before the non-empty one. Said from A to E option, user only fills C and D. System will give error said opt A and B is empty (while E is not reported as error). Code as below. Question is, is there any simpler way to do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/cyw8otLo/

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="optA" value="" /><br/>
    <input type="text" id="optB" value="" /><br/>
    <input type="text" id="optC" value="C" /><br/>
    <input type="text" id="optD" value="D" /><br/>
    <input type="text" id="optE" value="" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" />
</div>
```

Script

```
function getInputTextOf(searchStr, str, caseSensitive) {
    var optArr = {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D', 5: 'E'};

    var startIndex = 0, searchStrLen = searchStr.length;
    var index, indices = [];
    if (!caseSensitive) {
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        searchStr = searchStr.toLowerCase();
    }
    while ((index = str.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)) > -1) {
        indices.push(optArr[5 - index]);
        startIndex = index + searchStrLen;
    }
    return indices;
}

var $input = $('input:text'),
    $register = $('#register');

$('#register').on('click', function() {
    var trigger = true;
    var str = '';
    $($('div > input[id^="opt"]').get().reverse()).each(function (i) {
        str = str + ($(this).val() === '' ? 0 : 1);
    });

    var space = '*****';
    var start = str.indexOf("10"); //input start at 
    if (start > -1) {
        var abc = space.substring(0, start+1) + str.substring(start+1, str.length);
        var indices = getInputTextOf("0", abc, false);
        alert('Option ' + indices.sort() + ' still empty!');    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```js
var $input = $('input:text'),
  $register = $('#register');

$('#register').on('click', function() {
  var error, filled;

  $($input.get().reverse()).each(function() {
    if (this.value != '') {
      filled = true;
    } else if (filled && this.value == '') {
      error = true;
      return false;
    }
  })
  if (error) {
    alert('e')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="optA" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="text" id="optB" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="text" id="optC" value="C" /><br/>
  <input type="text" id="optD" value="D" /><br/>
  <input type="text" id="optE" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" />
</div>
```

Comment: I've modify your code with this to show what fields are empty https://jsfiddle.net/a0f7b258/ . But alert also show 'undefined'. Can you please tell why? And also, I modify your code, the 'this' part, to become '$(this)' , and it didn't work. I know that the $(this) is jquery object, but why it didn't work?

Comment: if you are `$(this)` then to get the value use `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).value`

Comment: And add sort function to var collect to sort the array, this code is complete. Many thanks. Mark as answered.

Comment: How careless I am. Yes you're right, jquery and pure js has different function name.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try something with setting a flag to boolean `false`:

```js
var flag = false;

$('input[type="text"]:not(:last)').each(function() {
  if ($.trim(this.value) == "") {
    $(this).addClass('error').focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    flag = true;
  }
  return flag;
});
```

```css
.error {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="optA" value="aaaa" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="optB" value="bbb" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="optC" value="C" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="optD" value="D" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="optE" value="" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah cool.. instead of informing all input that still blank, you make it focused on the first blank input founded. But your code still failed in this scenario: input A B C filled, this should not giving warning, since no blank input beeween the filled ones.

Comment: did I missed something here? Your code didn't work. It shows no error flag if I delete 'aaaa' for example.